# If a bug has been flagged as INVALID does that mean no solution will ever come?

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad Twist and I am having a recognized issue where the onboard touch pad and nipple don't work on first boot but they do after restart.

The full details (from someone else who discovered this problem before me) can be found here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1210748

While I understand that the finding in the bug report was that the BIOS may have caused  the problem to appear its still is a problem that doesn't happen if I run Windows 8.

I guess I'm just wondering if me and laptop have just been shown the door or if there's still hope for a fix.

Answer (score 2):

There was a reason why this bug was marked as *Invalid* as expressed by the one that mark [it as such](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1210748/comments/26):

> Marking invalid since this issue was introduced by the BIOS.
>
> Joseph Salisbury (jsalisbury) wrote on 2013-08-13

In this case, is Invalid because Ubuntu can't help but depends of a superior system (the BIOS maker) that introduced a bug. The fix should be introduced in a BIOS update made by the makers, since Ubuntu was *working fine* before the update,and Ubuntu is doing what is supposed to do. In this case, fix should come from the makers not Ubuntu developers.

Comment: Understood that already, was just hopeful that it didn't mean my device was left out.  Lenovo doesn't certify the device for Linux like some of their other ones and the BIOS update actually makes it more stable in Windows 8 so downgrading BIOS isn't really a good option for me.  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

They think it was caused by your BIOS updated not by Ubooboo.  So they're not going to fix it.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/Status

Invalid:

- This status should be used when the bug report does not contain
  adequate information to determine whether or not it is a bug even if
  it is resolved for the reporter
- This should also be used if the reported problem is not a bug at all, but for example user error
- It should be used conservatively as bugs marked as Invalid no longer show up in default searches
- Be sure to triple-check a bug before you invalidate it

On the bright side at least anyone who finds the bug report now (admittedly unlikely since it is marked as invalid) will know to downgrade their BIOS.

Comment: Agree however I can't figure out how to downgrade the BIOS. Lenovo doesn't "Certify" this device for Linux and without a BIOS backup I guess you'd have to know before you upgrade the BIOS.

Comment: Yeah I have no idea how to downgrade your BIOS.  Personally I never update them in the first place.  Unless they have huge security hole, it just isn't worth the risk of bricking your box.